# C alignment in union

Tags: c, alignment, unions

In the K&R C programming code, the following code is given

```
typedef long Align;     /* for alignment to long boundary */

union header {          /* block header: */
    struct {
        union header *ptr;     /* next block if on free list */
        unsigned size;         /* size of this block */
    } s;
    Align x;            /* force alignment of blocks */
};

typedef union header Header;
```

Then it goes on to say that "The Align field is never used; it just forces each header to be aligned on a
worst-case boundary". I have read the text multiple times but still do not understand why long is needed for alignment. SIZE is an int and PTR is 4 bytes, so shouldn't it be aligned anyways? And why use long, and not int? Thanks.

Comment: Did you realize that the way the code [was](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28245162/revisions) written in your question was completely wrong?

Comment: What if you compile in a 64 bit envirinment? Your ptr might be 64 bits, but size might only be 32 bits. The alignment variable x might help to align to a 64 bit boundary which might have some kind of use if you have an a array of the union.

Comment: @HenrikCarlqvist: In that case, `long` is unlikely to need stronger alignment than a union-pointer.

Answer (score 10):

That's a very old book.  At the time a pointer on many machines was only 16-bits, and a long was 32-bits, so the union forced alignment to 32-bits.

And as @Deduplicator points out, there are still many embedded systems that use 16-bit pointers.

---

Edit in response to the comment: The topic of alignment is fairly broad and full of nuance. To keep things simple, the discussion that follows makes these assumptions

- pointers are 16-bits
- `int` is 16-bits
- `long` is 32-bits
- the processor has strict alignment requirements, i.e. 16-bit values can only be accessed on 2-byte boundaries, 32-bit values can only be accessed on 4-byte boundaries.

The following structure would occupy 32-bits

```
struct header {
    struct header *ptr;     
    unsigned size;         
};
```

However, the fields within the structure are still 16-bits each. Therefore, the alignment requirement is still only 16-bits. So for example, placing the structure at address 0xAA02 would be perfectly valid since `ptr` would be at an aligned address (0xAA02) and `size` would also be at an aligned address (0xAA04).

However, the address 0xAA02 is not suitably aligned for the union, since the `x` field of the union requires 32-bit alignment. Thus, placing the structure into a union with `x` forces the compiler to place the structure on a 4-byte boundary, when otherwise it could be placed on a 2-byte boundary.

Comment: And that's **still the case** on most systems. Remember desktops, smartphones and tablets are the exception, and even they contain many smaller embedded chips.

Comment: @Deduplicator True, I neglected to consider the processor in my toaster :)

Comment: Well in that case, wouldn't that add up to 32-bits? An int is 16-bits and a pointer is 16-bits so that adds up to 32-bits. Doesn't that eliminate the need for long? I just don't see how adding the long type helps when the struct size is equal or larger than the long type.

Comment: Exactly my question. I was wondering how a `long` forces alignment while a pointer is 64 bits (for newly built computers in 2017). The answers helped a lot.